# Equivalent for Class_Terminate() in C#

Tags: c#

In VB 6.0 for a class I have this:

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
  Call MethodFoo(False)
  Set objet1 = Nothing
  Set object2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now I need to do the same in C#, I am not much worried about those two null object but that darn MethodFoo() that is getting called I need that one. Where is a safe place to add that in its C# equivalent class? ( and not in Finalizer method ), I am already getting weird errors because of having this finalizer method in my C# class and want to get rid of that too.

Comment: There is no equivalent, there is no deterministic destruction in .NET.  Using IDispose is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 4):

C# is garbage collected, meaning that there is no deterministic object cleanup.

Instead, you should implement `IDisposable` and use your class inside the [`using()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) block.

Comment: "and use your class inside the using() block" .. can you please explain this more? I know what is a using block but I don't get it how do you mean I use it? In the consumer ?

Answer (score 1):

Custom finalizers should be avoided in C#, as they are called non-deterministically by the Garbage Collector.

Implement `IDisposable` interface and use `Dispose()` method instead. **[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P)** is an article how to do it properly.